# Is there a way I can add more than one sprite in SpriteKit globally?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am struggling with one issue. Global declaration of my sprite so that I can interact with it. In this game, I have created a local sprite called enemy featured below:

```
func spawnEnemy() {   
let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "as")
let yPosition = CGFloat(frame.maxY - enemy.size.height)
let getXvalue = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: Int(frame.minX + enemy.size.width), highestValue: Int(frame.maxX - enemy.size.width))
let xPosition = CGFloat(getXvalue.nextInt())
enemy.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
enemy.name = "asteroid"
enemy.zPosition = 100
addChild(enemy)
let animationDuration:TimeInterval = 6
var actionArray = [SKAction]()
actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0), duration: animationDuration))
actionArray.append(SKAction.self.removeFromParent())
enemy.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
}
```

I want to tap the enemy to make it disappear from the screen. The variable is declared locally and not globally so the touchesBegan function does not "see" enemy. However, when I move the statement:

```
let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "as")
```

outside of local declaration and into global. It works until the code tries to spawn in another enemy and i get an error of "Tried to add an SKNode who already has a parent" This is the code I have running in my view did load:

```
run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run{self.spawnEnemy()
        }, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)])))
```

Every time it spawns a new enemy it crashes and says that the SKNode already has a parent which i understand. However, for my game to function I need the player to be able to touch the individual instance of that enemy and remove it. Hence my code for

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        if let location = touch?.location(in:self) {
            let nodesArray = self.nodes(at:location)
            if nodesArray.first?.name == "asteroid" {
                print("Test")
                enemy.removeFromParent()
                print("Test Completed")
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the error says unresolved use of "enemy" because the enemy is not global. I have been going back and forth on this issue for quite some time. If anyone has any potential solution or work around I would be very grateful, and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your enemies to their own class and handle the touch for each of those enemies in their own class. This cleans up your GameScene and keeps your code more organized. You can now add as many instances of enemy as you want.

FYI not related to this question but somethings to consider after you get this working

1. when game over or level change or win make sure you have a clean up function to remove all enemies
2. you should strongly consider recycling your objects vs creating them on the fly...better performance

try to separate as much code to your objects class as possible

```
class enemy: SKSpriteNode {

    init() {

        super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: CGSize.zero)

        setup()
    }

    func setup() {

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        name = "asteroid"
        zPosition = 100

        let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "as")
        imagine.zPosition = 1
        addChild(image)

        self.size = image.size

        animate()
    }

    func animate() {

        let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 6
        let move = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0), duration: animationDuration)
        let remover = SKAction.self.removeFromParent()

        run(SKAction.sequence(move, remover))
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        removeFromParent()
    }
}


class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run{ self.spawnEnemy()
         }, SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)])
        run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence))
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {

        let enemy = Enemy()
        let yPosition = CGFloat(frame.maxY - enemy.size.height)
        let getXvalue = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: Int(frame.minX + enemy.size.width), highestValue: Int(frame.maxX - enemy.size.width))
        let xPosition = CGFloat(getXvalue.nextInt())
        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
        addChild(enemy)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have always struggled with understanding these separated classes. The code worked and I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @crocs123 I'm glad it helped out